# exiftool process only regex matched source file

Tags: perl, photo, exiftool, organizer

I'm using `exiftool` to rename and organize the photos taken from a camera to a specified destination directory.

How can I specify the input source file name using regex?

Example:

I have a directory with these two files:

```
IMG_20160716_121830.jpg
IMG-20160716-121830-WA0004.jpg
```

I only want to process **IMG_20160716_121830.jpg**

Comment: Can you please show your command line?

Comment: Actually I didn't find any clue to how to start with these. I referred exiftool command examples and available options, I can see possible options to frame output based on input and to have control over extension.

Comment: What do you need a regex for? A single file name is not a pattern.

Comment: Okay. Show the command that you would use to erroneously process both files.

Comment: In the example you give you can simply check whether the name contains an underscore. `_` is the pattern for that.

Comment: @simbabque: I have posted an example of my files. The same I have to do recursively over a directory to find the files. That purpose i need to specify the file name as regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As user @Borodin mentions, in your example you only want files that have an underscore, not a dash.  In that case you just would search for files with an underscore.

But if that's a typo or if you need to recurse (wildcards don't work with exiftool's `-r` recurse option, see [Common mistake 2 & 3](https://sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/mistakes.html#M2)), then you can use exiftool's `-if` option to do a regex match on the filename.  In this case, you would add something like:
`-if "$filename=~/IMG-\d{8}-\d{6}\.jpg/"`
to you command (change double quotes to single quotes if on Mac/linux).